# Python file write twice when forking in `with`

Tags: python-2.7, file, fork

```
import os

m = 'foo\n' 
n = 'bar\n'

with open('test2.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write(m)

    os.fork()
    f.write(n)
```

The output make me confused:

```
foo
bar
foo
bar
```

But,what I expect is that:

```
foo
bar
bar
```

Then,I change the way to open file:

```
import os

m = 'foo\n'
n = 'bar\n'

fd = os.open('test2.txt', os.O_RDWR)
os.write(fd, m)

os.fork()
os.write(fd, n)
os.close(fd)
```

That works as I expected.

Is there a problem with `with` when `fork`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Python buffers files by default, and when you fork, if the buffer has not been flushed, then both processes will think they are responsible for flushing the buffer later, including the part from before the fork. If you add an explicit call to flush the stream right before you fork:

```
f.flush()
```

Then the `foo` will be written out that point, and the buffer will be emptied, ready for the parent and new child to both write `bar` without carrying the `foo` along.

Comment: Yes,I find the reason.Thanks